# Sparrow wallet suddenly not connecting to Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, sparrow-wallet

I setup a node running Bitcoin Core on a Windows PC and connected Sparrow Wallet to it from another Windows PC on the same local network. This worked fine for the last few weeks but now suddenly Sparrow won't connect to the node. Nothing has changed and all settings are the same. There probably was some Windows updates but nothing else has changed. Not sure what to do?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 pro on the node pc. Windows 11 on the sparrow PC.